# Excel Addin rejected because of Excel 2013

Tags: office-js, office-store

I developed an Excel Add-in that requires Excel 2016 (perpetual) or later.
So, I put these requirements tags in my manifest:

```xml
<Hosts>
  <Host Name="Workbook" />
</Hosts>
<Requirements>
  <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
    <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Is this enough to block my addin from Excel 2013 users, when the browse in the store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets), yes.

You should however make sure this aligns with the minimal version of ExcelApi that you're code is actually using. There have been a number of changes since `1.1` was released. If you're using anything that was released with version `1.2` through `1.6` (the latest GA release) then you need to specify that version as your minimum.

Comment: Thanks, so I don't understand why the Office Store team tested my Addin with Excel 2013. Maybe I have to send them the manifest file again, as the original manifest didn't have these requirements tags.
As for the API version, I'm using only 1.1, and the only time I used 1.6, I took care using `isSetSupported`.

Comment: If you didn't place this in requirements then it will show up as supporting Excel 2013.

Comment: I figured out that I didn't reupload the manifest file in the publishing page, I thought that just publishing the project from Visual Studio would do, so that must be the issue, thanks.